# button "Add to cart " don't work prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

after deleting the declinaisons of product ,button "Add to cart " don't work prestashop 1.6

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dRfz.jpg)

Comment: more detail plzz

Comment: i fixed this but i have another --> when i deleted declinaisons all the prices of products changes to 00.00 € in sub-categorys  list

Comment: @AouitiMouadh1 Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can answer your own question and describe how you fixed the problem. Also, if you have another issue or a follow-up question, it's best to [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and maybe include a link to this one. And remember to post your code -- that's very important to help other people answer your question.